# Subtracting sequential values with MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Starting with an ordered set of floating point values (the order matters) that can be retrieved with a simple query. I want to calculate sequential differences of values with a stored procedure. For instance,

if we have the values

1, 3, 7

the result should be

2, 4

What is the easiest way to do this with a stored procedure (Mysql 5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x (seq int);
INSERT INTO x VALUES (1), (3), (7);
SET @dif = 0;
SELECT seq - @dif, @dif:=seq FROM x ORDER BY seq;
```

Comment: I should have said this, but the values are floats.

Comment: The same routine works - just change 'int' to 'float'. You may need to round the results a bit.